# How to convert Standard Volume Event into High Volume Platform Events?

Tags: platform-event

With Spring 19, High Volume platform events are generally available. Now I want to convert my existing standard volume event into a high volume event.

I tried editing the event object in Setup, it did not give me an option to change the event type.

Secondly, I tried editing the object XML and converting `StandardVolume` into  `HighVolume` and then deploying via Metadata API(Force.com migration tool), the deployment succeeds without any error, but still, the event type is Standard Volume.

Can we convert Standard Volume event into High Volume Event?

**Edit**: If we cant convert, what can be the migration strategy?

If, I delete the Standard Volume object(pre destructive xml) and redeploy as High Volume, I will lose events in last 24 hours in Standard Bus. What can be best strategy for a seamless transition?

**Update from SF Support**: I have received a response form the team as the currently coverting Standard Volume to High Volume is not possible as of now(Team is working on the same. I don't see any specific SLA as of now but hope to be available within 2 releases).

Comment: Based on my ~14 years of Salesforce experience, if the docs do not say you *can* do something, you probably *can't*. I'm pretty sure you'll have to create a new event.

Comment: @sfdcfox , I thought the same. Can you advise migration strategy for seamless transition? I don't wanna lose events in Standard Volume bus when deleting.

Comment: @sfdcfox That's hardly a reliable rule. All sorts of stuff works despite being undocumented.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Lots of stuff *can* work despite being undocumented. I've had a rather enlightening discussion with a certain developer at Salesforce who has strongly advised *not* using undocumented stuff. It can work, or can it crash your entire org. The documentation are like guardrails. If you choose to ignore them, you do so at your own peril.

Comment: @sfdcfox I agree that we should avoid using undocumented functionality. I'm just saying that your comment is a bit misleading.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to Support if there's a way to change the `eventType` field for Platform Event objects created prior to Winter '19?

Comment: @JayantDas I would be raising a case today